# Retrieveing wso2 das API Usage information

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have a custom front-end set up and running in Grails. This is linked to WSO2 user creation and subscription and consequent clicks where user can invoke the API's published. I also have DAS configured with a custom dayabase(MySQL). I want to keep a graph in my frontend which will show the API Usage graph. How do I get this information? Is it possible by some REST call or probably directly by querying database? I have great scaling needs so querying might incur high latency costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API usage data are collected,analysed and exposed by DAS.DAS has [REST api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+REST+API+Guide) as well [javascript api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+JavaScript+%28JS%29+API) to retrieve the summarised data